# mqtt messaging.client javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, mqtt

i'm new to mqtt messaging client in javascript. can any one say that this code is written in client side or server side.

```
client = new Messaging.Client(location.hostname, Number(location.port), "clientId");
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});
function onConnect() {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log("onConnect");
    client.subscribe("/World");
    message = new Messaging.Message("Hello");
    message.destinationName = "/World";
    client.send(message);
};
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0)
        console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
};
function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
    client.disconnect();
};
```

can anyone write a server code in nodejs,javascript and socket. please give it. in advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The handler functions suggest that it is the client side.

PS: If you don't mind, could you tell us which library this is? Thanks.

Comment: can you please suggest the server side code in mqtt server. This is a nodejs with javscript and socket.io

Comment: I have done an mqtt nodejs app using the below as reference. Use npm to install this package https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js

Answer (score 0):

This is using the Eclipse Paho javascript client, http://eclipse.org/paho, which is for use within the browser.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to write server code with mqtt broker and javascript socket.io nodejs